# Merge two lists in special order in python

Tags: python, list, arraylist, concatenation

I have these 2 lists:

`char= ['aa', 'bb', 'cc']`

and

`number= [100, 200, 300]`

and I want the following :

`result = [ ['aa',100], ['bb',200], ['cc',300] ]`

thanks

Comment: what did you try?

Comment: @aws_apprentice actually I do not know what I suppose to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
char= ['aa', 'bb', 'cc']
number= [100, 200, 300]
result=zip(char,number)
list(result)
```

Comment: How about if i want thsi result  : `result = [ ('aa',100), ('bb',200), ('cc',300) ]`

Comment: I edited the comment and now I believe you will get the result as you need.

Answer (score 1):

You can use list comprehension and zip to build the list you desire.

```py
characters = ['aa', 'bb', 'cc']
numbers = [100, 200, 300]
result = [[x, y] for x, y in zip(characters, numbers)]
```